# Delete function and update function could not perform in cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

```
1) This is the create campaign activity which creates the campaign and candidate 

class CreateCampaignActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var startDateTimeTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var endDateTimeTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var titleEditText: TextInputEditText
    private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore

    private lateinit var candidate1Text: TextInputEditText
    private lateinit var candidate2Text: TextInputEditText
    private lateinit var candidate3Text: TextInputEditText
    private lateinit var addCampaignButton : Button



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_campaign)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar!!.title = "Create New Campaign"

        titleEditText = findViewById(R.id.textTitle)
        startDateTimeTextView = findViewById(R.id.start_date_time)
        endDateTimeTextView = findViewById(R.id.end_date_time)
        addCampaignButton = findViewById(R.id.btnAddCampaign)

        candidate1Text = findViewById(R.id.textCandidate1)
        candidate2Text = findViewById(R.id.textCandidate2)
        candidate3Text = findViewById(R.id.textCandidate3)

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()


        addCampaignButton.setOnClickListener {
            val title = titleEditText.text.toString().trim()
            val startDateTime = startDateTimeTextView.text.toString().trim()
            val endDateTime = endDateTimeTextView.text.toString().trim()
            val candidate1Name = candidate1Text.text.toString().trim()
            val candidate2Name = candidate2Text.text.toString().trim()
            val candidate3Name = candidate3Text.text.toString().trim()

            if (title.isEmpty() || startDateTime.isEmpty() || endDateTime.isEmpty() || candidate1Name.isEmpty() || candidate2Name.isEmpty() || candidate3Name.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this@CreateCampaignActivity, "Please fill up empty fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else if (!isEndTimeValid(startDateTime, endDateTime)) {
                // Show error message or toast indicating that end time must be after start time
                Toast.makeText(this@CreateCampaignActivity, "The end time must be after start time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.US)
                val startTimestamp = Timestamp(format.parse(startDateTime)!!)
                val endTimestamp = Timestamp(format.parse(endDateTime)!!)
                val campaign = Campaign(
                    id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                    title = title,
                    startDateTime = startTimestamp,
                    endDateTime = endTimestamp,
                    candidate1 = Candidate(
                        id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                        name = candidate1Name
                    ),
                    candidate2 = Candidate(
                        id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                        name = candidate2Name
                    ),
                    candidate3 = Candidate(id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(), name = candidate3Name)
                )
                // Add the campaign to the Firestore database
                db.collection("campaigns")
                    .add(campaign)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                        campaign.id = documentReference.id
                        Log.d(
                            TAG,
                            "Campaign successfully added to Firestore with ID: ${documentReference.id}"
                        )
                // Show success message or toast indicating that the campaign was successfully added
                        Toast.makeText(this@CreateCampaignActivity, "Campaign successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                // Clear the input fields
                        titleEditText.setText("")
                        startDateTimeTextView.text = ""
                        endDateTimeTextView.text = ""
                        candidate1Text.setText("")
                        candidate2Text.setText("")
                        candidate3Text.setText("")
                    // Navigate back to the previous activity
                        finish()
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error adding campaign to Firestore", e)
                        // Show error message or toast indicating that there was an error adding the campaign
                        Toast.makeText(this@CreateCampaignActivity, "Error adding campaign", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
            }

            startDateTimeTextView.setOnClickListener {
                showStartDateTimeDialog()
            }

            endDateTimeTextView.setOnClickListener {
                showEndDateTimeDialog()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun showStartDateTimeDialog() {
        // Code to show the DatePicker and TimePicker dialogs
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val dateSetListener = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, month, day ->
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day)
            val timeSetListener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, hour, minute ->
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
                startDateTimeTextView.text =
                    SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(calendar.time)
            }
            TimePickerDialog(
                this@CreateCampaignActivity,
                timeSetListener,
                calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                true
            ).show()
        }
        DatePickerDialog(
            this@CreateCampaignActivity,
            dateSetListener,
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        ).show()
    }

    private fun showEndDateTimeDialog() {
        // Code to show the DatePicker and TimePicker dialogs
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val dateSetListener = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, month, day ->
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day)
            val timeSetListener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, hour, minute ->
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
                endDateTimeTextView.text =
                    SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(calendar.time)
            }
            TimePickerDialog(
                this@CreateCampaignActivity,
                timeSetListener,
                calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                true
            ).show()
        }
        DatePickerDialog(
            this@CreateCampaignActivity,
            dateSetListener,
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        ).show()
    }

    private fun isEndTimeValid(startDateTime: String, endDateTime: String): Boolean {
        // Code to check if the end time is valid (i.e. after the start time)
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())
        val startDate = sdf.parse(startDateTime)
        val endDate = sdf.parse(endDateTime)
        return endDate?.after(startDate) ?: false
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CreateCampaignActivity"
    }
}


2) This is the edit campaign Activity to edit and delete campaign

class EditCampaignActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var datetimeTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var titleEditText: TextInputEditText
    private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore

    private lateinit var candidate1Text: TextInputEditText
    private lateinit var candidate2Text: TextInputEditText
    private lateinit var candidate3Text: TextInputEditText
    private lateinit var editCampaign : Button
    private lateinit var delCampaign: Button




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_campaign)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar!!.title = "Edit Campaign"


        titleEditText = findViewById(R.id.textTitle)
        datetimeTextView = findViewById(R.id.DateTime)
        delCampaign = findViewById(R.id.btndelCampaign)
        editCampaign = findViewById(R.id.btnSaveCampaign)
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        candidate1Text = findViewById(R.id.textCandidate1)
        candidate2Text = findViewById(R.id.textCandidate2)
        candidate3Text = findViewById(R.id.textCandidate3)

        intent.getStringExtra("CAMPAIGN_ID")
        val campaign = intent.getParcelableExtra<Campaign>("CAMPAIGN_DATA")

        if (campaign != null) {
            intent.putExtra("CAMPAIGN_ID", campaign.id)
        }
        if (campaign != null) {
            titleEditText.setText(campaign.title)
        }
        if (campaign != null) {
            datetimeTextView.text = campaign.endDateTime.toDate().toString()
        }
        if (campaign != null) {
            candidate1Text.setText(campaign.candidate1.name)
        }
        if (campaign != null) {
            candidate2Text.setText(campaign.candidate2.name)
        }
        if (campaign != null) {
            candidate3Text.setText(campaign.candidate3.name)
        }


        //Update function
        editCampaign.setOnClickListener {
            // Update the fields of the Campaign object
            val updatedTitle = titleEditText.text.toString()
            val updatedCandidate1 = candidate1Text.text.toString()
            val updatedCandidate2 = candidate2Text.text.toString()
            val updatedCandidate3 = candidate3Text.text.toString()

            campaign?.apply {
                title = updatedTitle
                endDateTime = Timestamp.now()
                candidate1.name = updatedCandidate1
                candidate2.name = updatedCandidate2
                candidate3.name = updatedCandidate3
            }

            if (campaign != null) {
                db.collection("campaigns").document(campaign.id)
                    .update(mapOf(
                        "title" to updatedTitle,
                        "endDateTime" to Timestamp.now(),
                        "candidate1" to mapOf(
                            "name" to updatedCandidate1
                        ),
                        "candidate2" to mapOf(
                            "name" to updatedCandidate2
                        ),
                        "candidate3" to mapOf(
                            "name" to updatedCandidate3
                        )
                    ))
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        // Update successful, show a message to the user
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Campaign updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        // Update failed, show an error message
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Error updating campaign: $it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
            }
                    // Confirm the edit action with the user
                    AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Edit Campaign")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to save the changes to this campaign?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
                            // Navigate back to the OrganiserActivity
                            finish()
                        }
                        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                        .show()
        }

       // perform delete function
        delCampaign.setOnClickListener {
            // Show a message dialog to confirm the delete action
            AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Delete Campaign")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this campaign?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
                    if (campaign != null) {
                        deleteCampaign(campaign)
                    }
                }
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show()
        }



    }

    private fun deleteCampaign(campaign: Campaign) {
        db.collection("campaigns").document(campaign.id).delete()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                // Navigate back to the OrganiserActivity
                finish()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                // Show an error message
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error deleting campaign: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't perform the delete and update function in the edit campaign activity. Whenever I created a new campaign from createCampaignActivity, I tried to edit the campaign and it states in the message dialog that [firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyPvn.png) has no document to update even though the document exists in the firestorm. How to solve this issue?

Comment: We can't see the value of `campaign.id` that you're using as the ID of the document, so we don't know what this code actually does.  Are you sure it's what you expect?  Hard coding the value or logging logging it, then edit the question to show the value.  We should be able to see that the ID matches what you show in the database.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.